# Need to extract data, starting from root site

Tags: web-scraping

I have a root site that has references to external web sites.

The objective is to collect some data from the root site and then jump to each referred site and to find some specific pages to collect wanted data.

I don't want to write this from scratch.

Does anyone know if such a scraper is available for purchase?

Comment: Web scraping is not data mining, I removed the tag. Data mining is advanced analysis, not data gathering.
There are plenty of web spider sources available on Google. Please don't abuse a *programming* question web site for search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit this site
     http://blog.outwit.com/?p=55